# $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_{n}\right) \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}[\mathbb{P}(A_n) - \mathbb{P}(B_n)]$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, inequality

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and two sequences $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(B_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements from $\mathcal{F}$ such that $B_{n}\subseteq A_{n}$ for every $n\geq 1$. Prove that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_{n}\right) \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}[\mathbb{P}(A_{n}) - \mathbb{P}(B_{n})]
\end{align*}

Since $B_{n}\subseteq A_{n}$, we know that $\mathbb{P}(A_{n} - B_{n}) = \mathbb{P}(A_{n}) - \mathbb{P}(B_{n})$. Based on it and the $\sigma$-subaditivity of the probability measure, I tried to proceed but without success.

Could someone give me at least a hint as how to solve it?

Comment: Consider $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(A_n - B_n)$ and apply subadditivity.

Comment: I see how it is related to the RHS, but how do I relate it to the LHS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $$\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) - \left(\bigcup_n B_n\right)
\subseteq
\bigcup_n (A_n - B_n).$$
Then,
$$P\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) - P\left(\bigcup_n B_n\right) = P\left(\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right) - \left(\bigcup_n B_n\right)\right) \le P\left(\bigcup_n (A_n - B_n)\right) \le \sum_n P(A_n - B_n)$$

Comment: thanks for the contribution! I was not aware of the first inclusion.

Comment: Just for curiosity, how do we prove the first inclusion?

Comment: @user1234 The left-hand side is equal to $\bigcup_n (A_n - (\bigcup_m B_m))$.